# If the dependent and independent variables are not stationary, but they are first difference stationary. Can I use the original variable?

Tags: regression, stationarity, differences, dependent-variable

If the dependent and independent variables are not stationary, but they are the first difference stationary. Can I use the original variable?.

If I use the percentage change for the dependent and independent in running regression is it ok for analysis?

Comment: Hi: that's a complicated question because, if they are cointegrated, you can use the original variables and estimate an ECM ( univariate case ) or a VECM ( multivariate case ). if they are not, then you need to difference them. so, you need to test for cointegration first. Testing for cointegration is another whole topic and the particular procedure depends on how many variables are involved. if there are only 2 variables, check out the engle granger methodology, if there are more than 2, then you need to use Johansen's method.